# Microsoft.Speech.Recognition работает не стабильно

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-speech-sdk

Начал работать с Microsoft.Speech. 
Есть код

```
     static System.Windows.Controls.TextBox l;


public void InitializeSpeechGrammar()
        {
        l = UserMessage;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

        Choices CommToRecognize = new Choices();
        CommToRecognize.Add(new string[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять" });

        GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        grammarBuilder.Culture = ci;
        grammarBuilder.Append(CommToRecognize);


        Grammar g = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }

 static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.7) l.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }
```

Сам по себе код рабочий. Т.е в режиме реального времени он может отследить говорите ли вы те слова которые вы описали. Но он может вообще не сработать, не "слышать" вас. Может работать 40 секунд и выгрузиться(перестать слушать). Может и до окончания работы программы работать.

Запускаю при старте программы.

```
   public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeSpeechGrammar();
        }
```

Вторая проблема - не дает заполнить

```
Choices CommToRecognize = new Choices();
```

Из словаря

```
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Action> keyValue in main.commands)
            {
               CommToRecognize.Add(keyValue.Key.ToString());
            }
```

> - $exception  {"\"Вызов конструктора для типа \"Assistant.MainWindow\", удовлетворяющего указанным ограничениям
>     привязки, привел к выдаче исключения.\": номер строки \"10\" и позиция
>     в строке \"9\"."} System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>
> Вызвано исключение: "System.FormatException" в Microsoft.Speech.dll
>   Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" в
>   mscorlib.dll Вызвано исключение:
>   "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" в mscorlib.dll Вызвано
>   исключение: "System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException" в System.Xaml.dll
>   Вызвано исключение: "System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException" в
>   System.Xaml.dll

и 3.
Возможно ли Начать слушать то что говорит пользователь после определенного слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

//задает интервал ожидания имеющий фоновый шум
engine.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

//задает интервал ожидания полной тишины (без шума)
engine.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

Есть еще свойства `EndSilenceTimeout` и `EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous` поэкспериментируйте с ними.

```
//задает пропуск перед распознаванием,т.е можно говорить, что хочешь
//до появления первого словарного слова распознаватель будет пропускать
builder.AppendWildcard();
//задает количество появлений слова минимум=0, максимум=1
builder.Append(“Привет”, 0, 1);
```

Про заполнение из словаря, извините не знаю, что подсказать. Может кто другой...

Comment: Да контрольное слово работает, но все равно после 2-3 команд выгружается

Comment: скачал, спасибо. Сейчас гляну