# У меня голосовой ассистент который должен отвечать на команды, но он выполняет пару команд, потом зависает. Что с кодом не так?

Tags: c#

У меня голосовой ассистент который должен отвечать на команды, но он выполняет 1-2 команды, потом зависает. Что с кодом не так?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static SpeechSynthesizer _SS = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        static void sayq(String words)
        {
            _SS.SpeakAsync(words);
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static Label l;

    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.52)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "один")
            {
                l.Text = "Один"; sayq("цифра один!");
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "два")
            {
                sayq("цифра Два!");
                l.Text = "Два";
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "привет")
            {
                sayq("Здравствуйте!!! Я голосовой помощник от pafimov! Спросите у меня что-либо или скажите комманды для списка команд!");
                l.Text = "Здравствуйте!!!";
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "пока")
            {
                sayq("До свидания!!!");
                l.Text = "Пока!";
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "команды")
            {
                sayq("открыть поиск, открыть профиль создателя, открыть соц сеть, пока, и так далее");
                l.Text = "Список команд";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        l = label1_result;


        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

        Choices numbers = new Choices();
        numbers.Add(new String[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "привет", "пока", "мяу", "гав", "команды" });


        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(numbers);

        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        if (Convert.ToString(g) == "один") { l.Text = "qqq"; }
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
}
```

Comment: Навскидку: используются локальные переменные, созданные в событии `Load`. Возможно, их убирает сборщик мусора. Сделайте их полями класса (формы). А именно `SpeechRecognitionEngine`.

Comment: А отладку делать пробовали?

Comment: Вы не одиноки. Видимо, библиотека капризная и надо почаще пользоваться try/catch. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612699

Comment: Спасибо всем я написал другой код